# Where is the Beligerent Boy Bulking Up to Beat Up His Brother? Because I'd Like to Bring him Biscuits,

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

An elderly woman named Marcia in the Commercial District has advised me that her grandsons are spoiling for a fight, and have respectively set about training to clobber each other once and for all for some reason or another.

Curiously, she has expressed a desire that the younger one win 'because he's her own flesh and blood'.

Rather than pry into whatever curious family legacy or potential adoptive situations might be involved here, I've decided to honor her request and bring a platter of biscuits to her grandson, Jiroque, who is supposedly training somewhere in the Residential District.

I have circled the Residential District, at every hour of night and day, and cannot find Jiroque. Where is this wanna be meathead? I just want to bring him some food from grandma.

Comment: [Biscuits?!?!](http://youtu.be/n1ZdtrobBKw?t=7s)

Comment: Plus one for alliteration!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find him punching a tree between the hours of 19:00 and midnight in the area shown below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Punching trees late at night... must be a Minecraft player.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz a Minecraft player would never do such a thing at night, unless it's an emergency, or a well lit area!